# How can I "add constraint *index name* unique ((case...))" in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm try to bring all index creations to the same style. [This](https://medium.com/flatiron-engineering/uniqueness-in-postgresql-constraints-versus-indexes-4cf957a472fd) article says that `add constraint ... unique` better than `create index unique`. And now I have a problem with indexes that contains `((case ...))`.
Can I use `add constraint ... unique` for this?

Comment: [Not for all unique indices](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/235037/188406) you can use `add constraint` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different from indexes, constraints can only be defined on columns, not on expressions. So if you need to enforce uniqueness on expressions, you have to `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX`.